# How would I put this code into 4 methods (Matrix Addition, Matrix Subtraction, Matrix Multiplication Matrix Division) and a main(called Driver)

Tags: java, matrix

```
public class matrixOperations {

public static void main(String args[]){
//lets create two matrix of dimentions 2*2
int x[][]={{1,2} , { 3, 4 }};
int y[][]={{1,4} , { 8,9 }};
int original[][] = new int[2][2];
// lets print original matrix x
System.out.println( " X matrix ");
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
System.out.print( x[i][j] + " ") ;

}

System.out.println( " ");
}
System.out.println( " ");
System.out.println( " ");

// lets print original matrix Y
System.out.println( " Y matrix ");
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
System.out.print( y[i][j] + " ") ;

}

System.out.println( " ");
}


System.out.println( " ");
System.out.println( " ");

//lets matrix sum be the result after the addition of matrix x and y ;

int sum[][] = new int[2][2]; //this will be 2*2 matrix

System.out.println( " addition matrix: X+Y ");
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {


sum[i][j] = x[i][j] + y[i][j];

System.out.print(sum[i][j] + " ");
}
System.out.println();//for generating new line after printing   single             row
}
System.out.println(" ");

System.out.println(" ");
// lets write code for matrix subtraction
// let matrix sub be the result after matrix subtraction
System.out.println( " subtraction matrix : X-Y ");
// sub matrix initialization
int sub[][] = new int [2][2];


for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {


sub[i][j] = x[i][j] - y[i][j];// only change

System.out.print(sub[i][j] + " ");
}
System.out.println(" ");//for generating new line after printing      single row
}
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");

// let's write code for matrix multiplication

//let matrix mul be the result after matrix multiplication
System.out.println( " multiplication matrix X*Y : ");
int mul[][] = new int[2][2];

for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
for(int j=0;j<2;j++)

{//initializing ith and jth element of mul matrix to be 0
mul[i][j]=0;
for(int k=0;k<2;k++)
{
mul[i][j]= mul[i][j] + x[i][k]*y[k][j];
}

// lets print the elements of the mul matrix
System.out.print(mul[i][j]+" ");
}
System.out.println( " "); // here one row gets printed so need to  change line
}

System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
// now lets write code for matrix division
// here every x[i][j] element will be divided by corresponding
//y[i][j] element
System.out.println( " division matrix X/Y :");
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
System.out.print(( (double)x[i][j] /(double) y[i][j]) + " ");
//here we need to typecast because integer division dosen't   gaurentees to produce result as integer
}
System.out.println(" ");// to change line after printing each row
}
}

}
```

Results should look like this I just need to break the code I do have into 4 methods and a main. I just don't know how to do it.

X matrix 
1 2
3 4

Y matrix 
1 4
8 9

addition matrix: X+Y 
2 6 
11 13

subtraction matrix : X-Y 
0 -2
-5 -5

multiplication matrix X*Y : 
17 22
35 48

division matrix X/Y :
1.0 0.5
0.375 0.444444444444444

Comment: What part of the task are you unsure about?

Comment: I actually figured it out! but Thanks